# addPersistentStoreWithType Returns Error 'attempt to insert nil key' for iCloud Storage

Tags: core-data, icloud, nspersistentstore

I'm trying to create a core data storage in iCloud, but when I try and add the persistent store for the first time (expecting creation), I get the error...

'-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil key'

I've seen a couple of other similar posts, but the recommendations are already in my code.  here is my code snippet.

```
        // set options
        NSURL *ubiquitousContentURL = [ubiq URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"TransactionLogs"];
        NSString *storeUbiquitousContentName = @"ProgressData";
        NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  ubiquitousContentURL, NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentURLKey,
                                  storeUbiquitousContentName, NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey, nil];

        // get url for progress db
        NSURL *progressUrl = [ubiq URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/LocalData.nosync/ProgressData.sqlite"];

        // create or open core data sql progress database
        NSError *error = nil;
        progressModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil] retain];
        progressContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        progressPsc = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:progressModel];
        [progressContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:progressPsc];
        [progressPsc lock];
        [progressPsc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:progressUrl options:options error:&error];
        [progressPsc unlock];
```

Thanks
Ray

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.  It seems I have to create the 'LocalData.nosync' directory manually.  It doesn't get created if it doesn't already exist.